# Run-time error '1004' - x1PasteValues is empty

Tags: excel, runtime-error, copy-paste, vba

I would like to copy paste constantly updating live data onto another sheet. Live data is linked to an original online source, so the formula is not a static value. Therefore, I've included in my code `PasteSpecial:=x1PasteValues` so that the macro copies the static values in that point in time.

However, when I try to run the macro Run-time error '1004' pops up and `x1PasteValues` appears as empty.

I believe the `PasteValues` function should work since I manually used `PasteSpecial` and it worked.

```
Sub copy_paste()

Worksheets("Sheet").Range("B2:B36").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

With Sheets("Sheet2")

    ab = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Time"
    .Cells(ab, 1).Value = Now

    Worksheets("Sheet").Range("H2:H36").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=x1PasteValues, Tranpose:=True

End With

Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "copy_paste"

End Sub
```

Comment: It's x**L**pastevalues, not x1pastevalues.

Comment: Your range declaration is also incorrect. You're selecting the last row in column B. You're then offsetting this by 1 which is past the max limit of rows on the sheet. This is probably where your error is

Comment: @Tom That also makes sense, however the macro still ran without errors with the Offset function in the code. It's only when I added the PasteValues function that it error-ed. I'll test your code below.

Comment: @Tom No he isn't - the `End(xlUp)` part is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. I'm assuming you want the contents of H to appear in the row next to your time stamp in Column A.

```
Sub copy_paste()
    Dim ab As Integer


    Worksheets("Sheet").Range("B2:B36").Copy

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("B1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

        ab = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Time"
        .Cells(ab, 1).Value = Now


        Worksheets("Sheet").Range("H2:H36").Copy
        .Range("B" & ab).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    End With


    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "copy_paste"

End Sub
```

Comment: This works! However, columns D, E, F, H are recording different things, ie. random times and random dates in a random order instead of the data in column H from the first sheet.

Also, the market is closed right now, so the data isn't live. I'll check in the morning if the values copied are static.

Thanks a lot Tom, I'm getting closer!